# Is there a file/place for server's human description?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I started to write a brief description of custom services, cronjobs... like server documentation to `/home/user/.servermeta` file to be able to quickly dive into the server environment after long time without logging in.

example:

```
[projects] - django_project - django web app inside ~/django_project
[services] - gunicorn daemon gunicorn.service

etc...
```

I'm just curious if there is some built-in way/file to do this in Linux so I know always where to look for such documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's never been a standard for this in the world of Linux/GNU. I think it's really up to you where and how to store such information.

I'd personally save it in the root directory, e.g. under `/info.txt` - why there? Because it's the most visible and prominent location.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea because it's not connected to any user.